# rdeskop to HDInsight

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight, cortana-intelligence

How can I connect to a HDInsight VM from Linux? Trying to connect with rdesktop gives me the error below.

```
rdesktop -u admin myclustername.azurehdinsight.net:3389
ERROR: Connection closed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Microsoft the remote desktop access is broken for Linux and Mac. They are working on fixing the issue.

Comment: At this point, Azure supports Linux-based HDInsight clusters. If you use those, you can connect to them via SSH.

Answer (score 0):

You must allow an exception for your ip in the Azure portal:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj553530.aspx

You should make sure you are not behind a firewall that is restricting traffic by IP or port.  Below is a list of the current Azure IP's.  HDInsight is mainly in the East US and Europe at this point, so those would be the regions and subregions you'd be most interested in.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn175718.aspx